# fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented error

Tags: swift, error-handling

Xcode is sending me the error "fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented error" despite being implemented. I don't know where the problem is.

```
final class newTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var inputFormTableView: UITableView!

    let form: Form
    let note = Note(name: "")

    init(form: Form) {
        self.form = form
        super.init(style: .grouped)
    }

    convenience init(note: Note) {
        let form = Form(sections: [
            FormSection(items: [
                TextInputFormItem(text: note.name,
                                  placeholder: "Add title",
                                  didChange: { _ in print("hello")})
                ])
            ])
        self.init(form: form)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        inputFormTableView.rowHeight = 44
        inputFormTableView.register(TextInputTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ReuseIdentifiers.textInput.rawValue)
        let new = newTableViewController(note: note)
        print(new.note.name)

    }

    private enum ReuseIdentifiers: String {
        case textInput
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    private func model(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> FormItem {
        return form.sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.item]
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return form.sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return form.sections[section].items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let object = model(at: indexPath)
        if let textRow = object as? TextInputFormItem {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ReuseIdentifiers.textInput.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! TextInputTableViewCell
            cell.configure(for: textRow)
            return cell
        }
        else {
            fatalError("Unknown model \(object).")
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to make UITableView act like an input form. For doing this, I am following this tutoriel : https://augmentedcode.io/2018/11/04/text-input-in-uitableview/. Everything works in the sample project but not mine.

Comment: The error is right: `init?(coder: NSCoder)` is **not** implemented. The code to initialize `form` and the `super` call is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't implemented it, you are just throwing a fatalError, when running from stroy-board this `init` is getting executed, replace the following code:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

With this:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    form = Form()
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```